Spring Boot Neo4j, How can i create a relationship with parametrized name?
i'm using Java Spring boot with a Neo4j server. My idea is to create a relation with the label given as a parameter.
I tried to use the $ like for a normal attribute:
@Query("MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r:$relationship]->(t)")
void createRelationship(String deviceId, String targetId, String relationship)

This is the error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Invalid input '$': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1, column 114 (offset: 113))
"MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r:$relationship]->(t)"
                                                                                                                  ^; Error code 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError'] with root cause

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '$': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1, column 114 (offset: 113))
"MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r:$relationship]->(t)"

The problem seems to be the $ in the label of the relationship.
I tried also in this way:
@Query("MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r::#{#relationship}]->(t)")
    void addTargetRelationship(@Param("deviceId") String deviceId,@Param("targetId") String targetId,@Param("relationship") String relationship);

But there is a similar error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Invalid input '$': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1, column 114 (offset: 113))
"MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r:$__SpEL__0]->(t)"
                                                                                                                  ^; Error code 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError'] with root cause

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '$': expected "%", "(" or an identifier (line 1, column 114 (offset: 113))
"MATCH (d:Device), (t:MonitoringTarget) WHERE elementId(d) = $deviceId AND elementId(t) = $targetId CREATE (d)-[r:$__SpEL__0]->(t)"

Someone has an idea on how i can approach this problem?
